# flutter multiline text field cursor moves below keyboard

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have created a textfield and enabled muiltiline so that I can add paragraphs. But the problem is that when I am typing more paragraphs the cusor moves below the keyboard and i cant see what i am typing.

However the text field does scroll up and down when viewing the overall text but how do i get the curso to be always above the keyboard when typing??

```
Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  width: width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    elevation: 12.0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        focusNode: textFocusNode,
                        controller: textController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                          hintText: '',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          focusColor: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        cursorColor: Colors.black,
                        maxLines: null,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```